# My navigation won't get &type=, what's wrong?

Tags: php, get

I have this for navigation, and when I switch to page 2, it will lose the &type=
Let's say I select "checked", the first page it shows fine, as it het the whole string,
but when I switch pages it loses... here's the code:

```
    // navigation
if($_GET['start'] && is_numeric($_GET['start']))
{
    $start=$_GET['start'];
    $start=((int)($start/$search_count))*$search_count;
}
else $start=0;
$info['curpage']=ceil(($start+1)/$search_count);
$info['total_pages']=ceil($info['total_results_count']/$search_count);
$navigation=array();
$navigation[]='<span class="navi navi_current"> -'.$info['curpage'].'- </span>'."\n";
$inc=$dec=$start;
$tcnt=0;
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++)
{
    $inc+=$search_count;
    $incp=ceil(($inc+1)/$search_count);
    $dec-=$search_count;
    $decp=ceil(($dec+1)/$search_count);
    if($inc<$info['total_results_count'])
    {
        array_push($navigation,'<span class="navi"> <a href="./?q='.$_GET['q'].'&start='.$inc.'"&type='.$_GET['type'].'>'.$incp.'</a> </span> '."\n");
        $tcnt++;
    }
    if($dec>=0)
    {
        array_unshift($navigation,'<span class="navi"> <a href="./?q='.$_GET['q'].'&start='.$dec.'">'.$decp.'</a> </span> '."\n");
        $tcnt++;
    }
    if($tcnt>=10) break;
}
$navigation=join("",$navigation);
// end navigation
```

I've tried adding **&type='.$_GET['type'].** to the array_unshift, but it doesn't work..
any help will be appreciated! thanks.

Comment: "I have code of mine, please debug it for me" is not a question everyone dream of

Comment: I'm learning php, i'm not asking to you to fix it, I wanna know what's wrong.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's outside of the quote:

```
'&start='.$inc.'"&type='.$_GET['type'].'
```

It should be

```
'&start='.$inc.'&type='.$_GET['type'].'"
```

(Notice the placement of the doublequote...

Answer (score 0):

In you code, you have done an error with the HTML-syntax:

```
<a href="./?q='.$_GET['q'].'&start='.$inc.'"&type='.$_GET['type'].'>
```

As you can see, the `"` is a little bit to early, in front of `&type=` when it should have been after. What you really want to do is

```
<a href="./?q='.$_GET['q'].'&start='.$inc.'&type='.$_GET['type'].'">
```

Answer (score 0):

If might be easier if you build the URL in advance:

```
$href = './?q='.urlencode($_GET['q']).'&start='.$inc.'"&type='.urlencode($_GET['type']);
array_push($navigation,'<span class="navi"> <a href="'.htmlspecialchars($href).'">'.$incp.'</a> </span> '."\n");
```

That makes it easier to apply proper encodings for the two contexts ([`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) for URL query and [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) HTML attribute value). Or doing this using [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query):

```
$args = array('q'=>$_GET['q'], 'start'=>$inc, 'type'=>$_GET['type']);
$href = './?'.http_build_query($args, '', '&amp;');
array_push($navigation,'<span class="navi"> <a href="'.$href.'">'.$incp.'</a> </span> '."\n");
```